# How to fill the width of the content in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

1. What I want is that to fill the width of the entire mobile screen with vuetify

with this code :

```
 <v-content>
    <router-view>
      <v-container fluid></v-container>
    </router-view>
  </v-content>
```

the router view has a margin on both left and right side

2. and that bottom-nav is already fitted on the screen and I won't be dragging the screen to show the bottom-nav

Comment: should `router-view` not be inside `v-container`? Container afaik has padding, so I presume you can just add `class="px-0"` to achieve full width

Comment: I copied from the documentation only

Comment: And as for your second question, it should be separate imo as it has nothing to do with original question (if I understood correctly).

Comment: if you remove `fluid` isn't working?

Comment: @Traxo yeah you're right, I just enumerated the questions. HAHA

Answer (score 12):

I needed to dynamically remove padding only on mobile, this works for me:

```
<v-container :class="{'px-0': $vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly }">
   <router-view> </router-view>
</v-container>
```

There is not much documentation that I could find as of now, but looking at the [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/src/components/VApp/mixins/app-breakpoint.js) I found these:

```
// Breakpoint ranges. 
xsOnly,
smOnly, 
smAndDown,
smAndUp,
mdOnly,
mdAndDown,
mdAndUp,
lgOnly,
lgAndDown,
lgAndUp,
xlOnly,
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also try this, vuetify has [helper classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing) to set padding and margin

```
<v-container fluid  class="pa-0 ma-0">
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

v-container creates a div with the class container. This class gives your div padding on all sides. (The amount changes depending on the [viewport breakpoint](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/grid); it's 2px for xs, 24px for xl). If you include the below in your css, your side padding should go away.

```
.container {
   padding: 0!important
}
```